# li items spanning more than one line are not aligned properly in css

Tags: css

I have a list in which I have few elements

```css
<style>.passengerBaggageList>ul li:first-child {
  list-style-type: none!important;
  list-style-position: inherit;
  padding: 0!important;
  width: 246.1pt;
}

.passengerBaggageList>ul li:not(first-child) {
  list-style: disc inside;
  width: 178pt;
}

.passengerBaggageList ul:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 13pt 0 0 0;
}

.extraLuggageCost {
  margin-right: 16pt;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="passengerBaggageList">
  <ul class="passengersLuggageList">
    <li>Mr.John Doe</li>
    <li>1 checked baggage</li>
    <li>1 extra checked baggage<span class="extraLuggageCost"> EUR 20</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="passengersLuggageList">
    <li>Mrs. Bea Doe</li>
    <li>1 checked baggage</li>
    <li>1 extra checked baggage</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the third li element contains more than one line or exceeds specified width, the content is not aligned, it should be exaclty below the above line. Also I need to put the span of extraCost class to the extreme right, which is not happening. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: are you open to use outside instead of inside in list-style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the  lists to stay aligned, you have to use `list-style-position:outside`, which will move the bullet points out of the element.
In your example, I put it in `list-style : disc outside;`

Here's a code snippet:

```css
ul li:first-child{
    list-style-type: none!important;
    padding : 0!important;
    width : 246.1pt;
}

ul li:not(first-child){
    list-style : disc outside;
    width : 178pt;
}

ul:not(:first-child){
    margin: 13pt 0 0 0;
}

.extraCost{
    margin-right: 16pt;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Mr. JOHN DOE</li>
    <li>1 extra luggage</li>
    <li>1 checked extra luggage for the adult will cost the passenger the following cost from the book described by airline laws<span class="extraCost"> EUR 20</span></li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Out of element, not the parent element

Edit2: Removed the JSFiddle and replaced it with a code snippet.

Comment: If you still wanted to have the passenger name left-aligned with the list bullets, you can add margin-left:-13pt; to the first child css

Answer (score 1):

In your style tage add a list-style-position element to your ul/li selector and set the propery to outside:

```
ul li:not(first-child){
    list-style : disc inside;
    width : 178pt;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```